# Can I install Ubuntu into a RPi2 remotely?

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, raspberry-pi, remote

One friend of mine would like to install ubuntu mate into his new Raspberri Pi 2, but he would like me to help him trough the installation steps. My problem is that I am not aware if Ubuntu can run the start the installation with:

- network enabled (give he has connected the RPi with Ethernet and DHCP works)
- VNC for GUI Installation
  or SSH for ncurses text-based installation

Comment: did you look at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problrm with *PIs is that you can only boot from SD Card. So you need any system installled on the sd card to boot. You can use the CoreFS from Ubuntu and add the rpi kernel to it. After that you can configure the whole system remotely. Here is an example for a BananaPi, you can modify it for RPI: https://endercoding.com/endercoding/bananapi-bsp

Comment: In theory tho, You could store only a boot loader on the SD card and boot a live environment on a CD/DVD. This is not impossible and could enable you to remotely install a Ubuntu onto the "RPi" itself. Or a external drive. Since once loaded it all runs in RAM anyway.

Comment: Right, but you have to use u-boot as far as I know. And after that, you have to copy the kernel yourself because ubuntu repos have not any kernel packages for pi-spacific hardware. (LEDs...)